# How is it possible to have a hostname for https without checking "Require Server Name Indication"?

Tags: ssl, https, iis-8, sni

When editing a https site binding, there's an option to add a host name, which makes the web server successfully able to differentiate between websites using the same IP address. There's also an option to "Require Server Name Indication".

My question is, how can I have a host name on an https binding *without* requiring server name indication?

Isn't server name indication the technology that enables host names for https bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website must be accessible for clients without SNI support, that website (domain) must be the default one configured in your webserver.

Comment: I have a site bound with https, where the host header is set to a sub-domain and the SNI checkbox is unchecked. It works. Does it make a difference that the certificate has the sub-domain on it?

Comment: If the certificate presented by your default domain contains the not-default-domain asked, then that domains is accessible without SNI. When you check your domain with ssllabs.com it tells you if it's compatible with client without SNI support.